# Laravel Xero Integration Cetificate Issue

Tags: php, laravel, openssl

I have followed a tutorial https://github.com/amochohan/xerolaravel
for integrating xero to laravel, everything went well, i got config file generated, changed consumer key and consumer secret key added path but still can't get through this stupid error: I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

```
Cannot access private key for signing: openssl_pkey_get_private('file:///C:
/PathToVendorFolder/vendor/src/drawmyattention/xerolaravel/Certificates/private
key.pem') returned false
```

The only thing comes in my mind is path but if i open the same path in explorer my certificate file gets open. The otherthing that comes to mind is my openssl, but i think its the one that i am supposed to use, anyways how would i find that it I have to change my openssl version or something, currently I am using openSSL 64 bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like you might be using windows. The absolute path is `file://`, however on *nix systems the 3rd `/` represents the path from the Home directory. That would not apply to you on Windows, so you would just use `file://` instead.

Comment: Yup, figured that out.. though got stuck with other problem, ahh